# Is there a way to know that a migration is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model and I want to "register" meta-data about the columns, e.g. a label, description, in an initializer.

As part of this I want to check the column actually exists and raise if not.

However the column will not exist until the migration to add the column has been run.

Therefore I wish to skip this check if the environment is being initalized for the purposes of a migration.

Is there a way to know that a migration is running? Or that the `db:migrate` rake task triggered the loading of the environment...

```
class Preferences < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.register(attrs)
    raise if migration_not_running? && !column_names.include?(attrs.fetch(:column_name))
    @schema << atrs
  end

  def self.schema
    @schema ||= []
  end

  private

  def self.migration_not_running?
    # ...?
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What about checking if there are pending migrations, like the server does, when you try to load the views.

There's [ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-c-check_pending-21), which raises `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` if there are ones. But it uses `connection.migration_context.needs_migration?` logic under the hood, so it can be checked just like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
```

I understand, that it doesn't directly answers your question, but it's suggesting a possible alternative.

Comment: This works great, thanks. I will accept shortly should no other answers arrive.